# ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople not getting contacts stored on SIM Card

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I'm using the code provided from the accepted answer at [Retrieve all contacts phone numbers in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975297/retrieve-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-ios) and I've noticed a lot of contacts are missing. I'm pretty sure they're contacts stored on the SIM card and somehow ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople doesn't retrieve contacts from the SIM card. If I use `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` the contacts do appear, but that isn't suitable for what I'm building.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Missing contacts in ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581740/missing-contacts-in-abaddressbookcopyarrayofallpeople) had the answer. Although it wasn't entirely clear at first what the poster did, the main thing was casting the `ABMultiValueRef` to an `NSArray` like so:

```
ABMultiValueRef phones = (__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
NSArray *phoneNumbers = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phones);
```

After that `phoneNumbers` contains every phone number for the current `ABPerson`.